# How to pass to next line that cutted elements in a list?

Tags: html, css, list, line

I have list and with some css I sorted them into one line in a box.

```
<div class="box">  
<ul>
   <li>
       <a href="http://www.google.com">Example Link Sample</a>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {width:500px; margin:auto;}

li {display:inline;}
```

But some list elements which is in end of line cutted.
How can I force them to another line if they cutted.

Here's example: http://jsfiddle.net/P5D8u/

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/m0i88

Comment: What does "cutted" mean?

Comment: Can you explain the problem a little better or include a picture of what you are seeing? I've tried both Chrome and IE and the list looks correct to me.

Comment: ya its look fine for me too

Comment: Here it's: http://prntscr.com/m0i11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

`display:inline;` on your `li` element is causing the 3rd one to flow to the next line.

Comment: I've updated your JS Fiddle and there is no breaking: http://jsfiddle.net/P5D8u/7/.  Please provide code which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I see it in Opera, but I don't understand why.  The code looks correct to me.

Comment: I use in Opera, fine with Chrome, could you confirm is it Opera's bug?

Comment: Yeah, it works now. Thanks cimmanon and KatieK. Is Opera renders spec incorrectly?